# Вопрос про сказуемое в предложении "Делай хорошо"

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

Если ты что-нибудь делаешь, делай хорошо.
Первая грамматическая основа - ты делаешь, а вторая - делай или делай хорошо?

Comment: @Екатерина Сорина, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Если ты что-нибудь делаешь, делай (это) хорошо.**

***Делай хорошо*** ― главное предложение, оно односоставное (определенно-личное), предикативной основой (сказуемым) является глагольная форма ***делай***, обстоятельство ***хорошо*** в предикативную основу не входит.

**Но вот почему возник такой вопрос?** Это связано с тем, что  сказуемое может быть выражено **устойчивым словосочетанием** со значением одного слова, например ***оказать помощь*** (помочь), ***проявлять заботу*** (заботиться).

**Но ведь это не наш случай,** в приведенном примере нет устойчивых словосочетаний, и тем не менее без наречия ***хорошо*** предложение **кажется незаконченным, не имеющим смысла.**

Всё дело в том, что надо **отличать грамматику** (само предложение) от его **семантики** (сообщения, высказывания, заключенного в нем), это разные вещи. В грамматике мы выделяем предикативную основу (подлежащее и сказуемое), а **по смыслу мы делим предложение на тему (о чём говорим) и рему (что говорим)**.

Тогда ***делай*** ― это тема (предмет), а ***хорошо*** ― сообщение о предмете. Вот и получается, что **без наречия сообщения не будет**, коммуникативная функция нарушена, и мы не понимаем, что нам хотели сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо - здесь  наречие. Делай как? - хорошо. Следовательно, не может быть частью грамматической основы.

Comment: И знак удивительный (!) не надо игнорировать.

Comment:  shampar, я вас не совсем понял. Что значит ''Знак удивительный (!)не надо игнорировать"?

Comment: хорошо - обстоятельство, речь ведь о членах предложения, а не о частях речи.

Comment: А не является ли тут "хорошо" частью сказуемого? Мне кажется, оно весьма тесно связано с ним.